# QGIS python reports

Tags: qgis, python

I am developing a plugin for QGIS which one of its functionalities is to create different reports in *.pdf* taking the data from a PostGIS database.

The software I am using to create the reports is: [iReport 5.6.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ireport/files/iReport/iReport-5.6.0/).

The package used to generate the reports is JasperReports 6.3.1 library through JasperStarter v3.1 command-line tool.

The problem comes when I try to use the library **[pyreportjasper](http://pythonhosted.org/pyreportjasper/)** from my plugin code like this:

`import pyjasper
import os
def compileJasper(self):
        input_file = 'report.jasper'
        output = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '\output'
        jasperpy = pyjasper.jasperpy
        jasper = jasperpy.JasperPy()
        jasper.process(
            input_file, output, format_list=["pdf", "rtf"])`

The error I get:

```
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyjasper\jasperpy.py", line 144, in process
            return self.execute()
          File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyjasper\jasperpy.py", line 183, in execute
            output = subprocess.check_call(self.command, shell=True)
          File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 542, in check_call
            raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
        CalledProcessError: Command 'jasperstarter --locale pt_BR process "[INPUT_PATH]\report.jasper" -o "[OUTPUT_ROUTE]\output" -f pdf rtf' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

it seems that this library uses *subprocess.run()*  and this function is implemented in Python 3.5. As far as I know, QGIS uses Python 2.7.

I’ve tried to use the console with: `jasperstarter --locale pt_BR process "[INPUT_PATH]\report.jasper" -o "[OUTPUT_PATH]\output" -f pdf rtf` and it generates the report successfully

Does any one know how to deal with this issue?

If not, does anyone know another software alternative to create reports from a QGIS plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally used

```
class MyPDFGenerator():
    def __init__(self):

        self.driver = "C:/JasperStarter/bin/jasperstarter.exe --locale es_ES process"
        self.name= " [input_path]/report2.jrxml"
        self.out= " -o [output_path] -f pdf"
        self.bd = " -t postgres -u postgres -H [host]-n [name]-p [pass]--jdbc-dir C:\driver"
        self.parametter= " -P codmuni=8"

    def makePDF(self):        
        cmd= self.driver + self.name+ self.out+ self.bd + self.parametter
        os.system(cmd)
```

in C:\driver I have postgresql-42.1.1.jar file

More documentation in [JasperStarter](http://jasperstarter.cenote.de/usage.html#Reports_with_runtime_parameters)